# How to write a file byte by byte using c++

Tags: c++

How to write a file byte by byte using c++?

```
unsigned short array[2]={ox20ac,0x20bc};
```

if i have a hexadecimal value 0x20ac how can i write it byte by byte in a file using c++

Comment: Wouldn't you prefer to write it in one go?

Comment: `out.write(reinterpret_cast<char const*>(array), sizeof array)` will let you write out the underlying byte representation.

Comment: @Simple, doesn't that require knowing endianness?

Comment: @leewangzhong depends on whether endianness is an issue or not.

Comment: As an answer for a non-esoteric question on StackOverflow, I think we should strive to be complete as far as the question asked, so we should include relevant details for those that find the question.

Answer (score 10):

You can try something like this:

```
#include <fstream>
...

ofstream fout;
fout.open("file.bin", ios::binary | ios::out);

int a[4] = {100023, 23, 42, 13};
fout.write((char*) &a, sizeof(a));

fout.close();
```

Comment: If intention was to write byte by byte rather than 4 bytes at a time you would want to use char or unsigned char as opposed to int.

Comment: The `ios::out` specifier is superfluous when you are working with a `std::ofstream`

Answer (score 6):

One option, using standard C++ library:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <assert.h>

void main()
{
    unsigned short array[2]={ox20ac,0x20bc};

    std::ofstream file;
    file.open("C:/1.dat", std::ios_base::binary);
    assert(file.is_open());

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]); ++i)
       file.write((char*)(array + i * sizeof(array[0])), sizeof(array[0]));
    file.close();
}
```

Alternatively, you can easily write your whole data in one go (without a loop):

`file.write((const char*)array, sizeof(array));`

Comment: This will write the same byte twice.

Comment: Now your first code will write two out of the four bytes contained in the array (the first byte of each element). And the one-liner should just have `sizeof(array)`, not divided by `sizeof(array[0])`.

Comment: I couldnt open the output file.

Comment: @Venkatesan: do you mean my assertion has failed? Are you on Windows?

Comment: If i give  one byte hex values in the array say 0x0056.Its working fine.if it is 0x20ac i cant able to open the file

Comment: @Venkatesan: edited the answer. It is no longer writing bytes, it's writing array elements (`short`, 2 bytes).

Comment: You can change the filename to something in a directory to avoid the permissions issues, like `"C:/temp/1.dat"`.  The root directory is protected by default.

Comment: @RetiredNinja: I think his problem is outside of the scope of this question.

Comment: 1. A byte is two hexadecimal digits. 0x20AC is two bytes (four digits). 2. 0xAC is not an ASCII value, so it isn't normally printable. That means simpler (normal) editors like Notepad won't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

To open an output file, use ofstream (output file stream, a subclass of ostream). Use the ios_base::binary mode (as second argument in the constructor or the open() member function) if you're not sure whether your output is human-readable text (ASCII).

To write a single byte, use the ostream member function "put". To write more than one byte at a time, use the ostream member function "write".

There are ways of taking data types (int, for example) longer than one byte and using them as arrays of bytes. This is sometimes called type-punning and is described in other answers, but beware of endianness and different sizes of data types (int can be 2-8 bytes), which can be different on different machines and compilers.

To test your output, reopen it as an input file and print the bytes.

```
ifstream in("myfile.txt", ios_base::binary);
while(!in.eof()) printf("%02X ", in.get()); //print next byte as a zero-padded width-2 capitalized hexadecimal).
in.close();
```

Or just use a hex editor like normal people.

Answer (score -5):

you can use write function or ostream .
Use c++ function is ostream.