# Write real binary to file

Tags: c++, file, binary, binaryfiles

I am currently working on a project to read binary data from a file do stuff with it and to write it back again. The reading works well so far, but when I try to write the binary-data stored in a string to a file, it writes the binarys as text. I think it has soemthing to do with the opening mode.
Here is my code:

```
void WriteBinary(const string& path, const string& binary)
{
    ofstream file;
    file.open(path);
    std::string copy = binary;
    while (copy.size() >= 8)
    {
        //Write byte to file
        file.write(binary.substr(0, 8).c_str(), 8);
        copy.replace(0, 8, "");
    }
    file.close();
}
```

In the function above the `binary` parameter looks like this: `0100100001100101011011000110110001101111`

Comment: So presumably that's exactly what's in the `binary` object: A sequence of `0` and `1` text characters.

Comment: Yes, but let's say i have the binary string mentioned in the question and write it to a file with the function shown in the question, the file won't contain `Hello`, which is what the string means in ascii. It's just the numbers.

Comment: If you want to write `Hello` to the file, you'll need to convert that binary string to the bytes `H`, `e`, `l`, `l`, `o`.

Comment: I just tried your solution and it really worked. Therefore I used the function of yasen described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20400128/how-to-write-a-file-byte-by-byte-using-c) post. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of "aschelper" I was able to create a solution for this problem. I converted the binary string to its usual representation, before writing it to the file. My code is below:

```
// binary is a string of 0s and 1s. it will be converted to a usual string before writing it into the file.
void WriteBinary(const string& path, const string& binary)
{
    ofstream file;
    file.open(path);
    string copy = binary;

    while (copy.size() >= 8)
    {
        char realChar = ByteToChar(copy.substr(0, 8).c_str());
        file.write(&realChar, 1);
        copy.replace(0, 8, "");
    }
    file.close();
}


// Convert a binary string to a usual string
string BinaryToString(const string& binary)
{
    stringstream sstream(binary);
    string output;
    while (sstream.good())
    {   
        bitset<8> bits;
        sstream  >> bits;
        char c = char(bits.to_ulong());
        output += c;
    }
    return output;
}

// convert a byte to a character
char ByteToChar(const char* str) {
    char parsed = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        if (str[i] == '1') {
            parsed |= 1 << (7 - i);
        }
    }
    return parsed;
}
```